# Android - Soft keyboard hides when long press on field

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

When I open any input field in my app, soft keyboard is shown.
But when I switch to another field, or click on same field again, or long-press on same field, keyboard gets hidden.

How I can disable this behavior? I checked other apps and they do not hiding keyboard when long-pressing.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKb6S.jpg

Reason why I need this: Some input fields (mostly multiline EditText) inside scrollable view are jumping all around screen when I want to copy/paste something, because keyboard show/hide each click.

Comment: Are you explictly removing focus somewhere in your code?  Something is telling the OS to not show a keyboard anymore, and focus is the usual culprit there.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, there was an global onTouch handler what was hiding it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had `override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean` in BaseActivity what was hiding keyboard everytime `focu`s was not `null`. That was the reason why I had this behavior.